# Unreachable code error when specifying if condition in return block in c#

Tags: c#

I need do and if condition in my return block in c# . I get a compile time error saying unreachable code. If you notice , I am passing parameter showCommercialOption. I need to implement if(!showCommercialOption) then don't show Commercial section. How do I achieve that ?

```
 private static Models.NpvResults BuildNpvResult(NpvResults npvResults, bool showCommercialOption)
        {
            return new Models.NpvResults
            {
                //Commercial
                CommInsYear = npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
                CommInsPremiumPaid = npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.premPaid).ToArray(),
                CommInsTaxDeduction = npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.taxDeduction).ToArray(),
                CommInsDiscountedTaxDeduction = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction).ToArray(),
                CommInsDiscountedLossesPaid = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedLossesPaid).ToArray(),
                CommInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.CommIns.ToArray(),

                //SelfIns
                SelfInsYear = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
                SelfInsDiscountedLossesPaid = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedLossesPaid).ToArray(),
                SelfInsDiscountedTaxDeduction = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction).ToArray(),
                SelfInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.SelfIns.ToArray(),
                //Captive
                CaptiveInsYear = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
                CaptiveInsPremiumPaid = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.premPaid).ToArray(),
                CaptiveInsTaxDeduction = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.taxDeduction).ToArray(),
                CaptiveInsLoanToParent = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.loanToParent).ToArray(),
                CaptiveInsCapitalContribution = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.capContriDistr).ToArray(),
                CaptiveDividentDistribution = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.dividendDistr).ToArray(),
                CaptiveInsTerminalValue = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.terminalVal).ToArray(),
                CaptiveInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.CaptiveIns.ToArray()
            };
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried a google search on the “if-then-else” construct?

Comment: You are still returning the new object. What value you want for the properties of this object instance if showCommercialOption is false?

Comment: What do you mean with "don't show Commercial section"?

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to split it up to an object initializer and an if-block. This would require an intermediary variable...

```
private static Models.NpvResults BuildNpvResult(NpvResults npvResults, bool showCommercialOption)
{
    var m = new Models.NvpResults()
    {
        //SelfIns
        SelfInsYear = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
        SelfInsDiscountedLossesPaid = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedLossesPaid).ToArray(),
        SelfInsDiscountedTaxDeduction = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction).ToArray(),
        SelfInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.SelfIns.ToArray(),
        //Captive
        CaptiveInsYear = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
        CaptiveInsPremiumPaid = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.premPaid).ToArray(),
        CaptiveInsTaxDeduction = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.taxDeduction).ToArray(),
        CaptiveInsLoanToParent = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.loanToParent).ToArray(),
        CaptiveInsCapitalContribution = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.capContriDistr).ToArray(),
        CaptiveDividentDistribution = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.dividendDistr).ToArray(),
        CaptiveInsTerminalValue = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.terminalVal).ToArray(),
        CaptiveInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.CaptiveIns.ToArray()
    };

    if (showCommercialOption)
    {
        m.CommInsYear = npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray();
        m.CommInsPremiumPaid = npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.premPaid).ToArray();
        m.CommInsTaxDeduction = npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.taxDeduction).ToArray();
        m.CommInsDiscountedTaxDeduction = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction).ToArray();
        m.CommInsDiscountedLossesPaid = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedLossesPaid).ToArray();
        m.CommInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.CommIns.ToArray();
     }

     return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been sufficiently answered by Sebastian. However you could use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), though this is pretty smelly IMO

> The conditional operator (?:), commonly known as the ternary
>   conditional operator, returns one of two values depending on the value
>   of a Boolean expression.

```
return new Models.NpvResults
   {
      //Commercial
      CommInsYear = !showCommercialOption ? null : npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
      CommInsPremiumPaid = !showCommercialOption ? null : npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.premPaid).ToArray(),
      CommInsTaxDeduction = !showCommercialOption ? null : npvResults.CommIns.Select(x => x.taxDeduction).ToArray(),
      CommInsDiscountedTaxDeduction = !showCommercialOption ? null : npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction).ToArray(),
      CommInsDiscountedLossesPaid = !showCommercialOption ? null : npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedLossesPaid).ToArray(),
      CommInsGraphData = !showCommercialOption ? null : npvResults.GraphData.CommIns.ToArray(),

      //SelfIns
      SelfInsYear = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
      SelfInsDiscountedLossesPaid = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedLossesPaid).ToArray(),
      SelfInsDiscountedTaxDeduction = npvResults.SelfIns.Select(x => x.discountedTaxDeduction).ToArray(),
      SelfInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.SelfIns.ToArray(),
      //Captive
      CaptiveInsYear = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.year).ToArray(),
      CaptiveInsPremiumPaid = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.premPaid).ToArray(),
      CaptiveInsTaxDeduction = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.taxDeduction).ToArray(),
      CaptiveInsLoanToParent = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.loanToParent).ToArray(),
      CaptiveInsCapitalContribution = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.capContriDistr).ToArray(),
      CaptiveDividentDistribution = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.dividendDistr).ToArray(),
      CaptiveInsTerminalValue = npvResults.CaptiveIns.Select(x => x.terminalVal).ToArray(),
      CaptiveInsGraphData = npvResults.GraphData.CaptiveIns.ToArray()
   };
```